# get property of version in JIRA REST - how to use search jql?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to get 2 properties of Jira's `versions`, namely to check whether it was `released` or not and get his `name`. How can i get this information with `REST`?

Up to now i have managed to get the versions `JSON`, by using: `https://myproject/rest/api/2/project/projectkey/versions/`

but when i try to add a `search?jql=released=false` i get a `status 404`...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Volodymyr answered your original question properly.

The answer to your second question is that you cannot filter the versions that way. [JIRA REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/) uses the following URL scheme

```
http://host:port/context/rest/api-name/api-version/resource-name
```

and this is transformed to your current URL as

```
https://myproject/rest/api/2/resource-name
```

The resource-name part is the key. There are multiple resources which you could use. One of them is the `project` other is the `search`. On the same documentation page you can find the details of each resources where you could see that the [project](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e5790) resource is basically used to query the projects. There are some other URL's for querying a specific project and some important attibutes (like [all](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e5936) of the versions, or just a [specific](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e5961) version).

The [search](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e1303) resource is used to query JIRA *issues*. The syntax which you added to your post is resembles of an issue query. These two cannot be mixed. You can read more about the JQL syntax on the [Advanced searching](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/advanced-searching-179442050.html) page of the JIRA documentation

AFAIK the JIRA REST API doesn't provide a way where you could query "the unreleased versions for a given project". You have to query all the versions and filter out the results programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you need to find all released versions by iterating results from /rest/api/2/project/projectkey/versions/ and then you can search for issues that are mapped to these versions:

```
 fixVersion in ("1.1", "1.2")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer!!! i will try it as soon as i get to the PC and let you know how it worked :D